# Is there a way to rearrange the contents of a list of arrays?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to rearrange an array of objects such that the contents are rearranged such that all the x<sup>th</sup> elements are grouped in another array? I'm not sure the best way to explain this so I'll illustrate with an example:

theArray has 5 properties: number, color, size, height, quality. There are 50 instances of this array, each with different properties.

I want to rearrange this so there are 5 arrays with 50 items inside each array.

The way I would do it is:

```
NSMutableArray *innerTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:49];
NSMutableArray *outerTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

for (int i = 0 ; i < [theArray count]; i++){
    [innerTemp addObject:[[theArray objectAtIndex:i] number]];
    [innerTemp addObject:[[theArray objectAtIndex:i] color]];
    [innerTemp addObject:[[theArray objectAtIndex:i] height]];
    [innerTemp addObject:[[theArray objectAtIndex:i] age]];
    [innerTemp addObject:[[theArray objectAtIndex:i] quality]];

    [outerTemp addObject:temp];
}
```

So I guess my question is, is there some easier way/more efficient to do this?

Comment: So the array stores a custom object with the properties `number`, `color`, etc?

Comment: yea, each array has an object with 5 properties

Comment: @trojanfoe: Or just see mine (already there). :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use KVC ([Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/)):

Assuming your class looks something like this:

```
@interface InstanceClass : NSObject

// IIRC properties need to be objects (hence the NSValue around NSSize), there is no auto-wrapping.
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *number;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSColor *color;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSValue *sizeValue;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *height;
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *quality;

@end
```

and you have an array like

```
NSArray *instances = @[instance1, instance2, instance3, instance4, ...];
```

then this would be all you need:

```
NSArray *numbers   = [instances valueForKey:@"number"];  // array of numbers.
NSArray *colors    = [instances valueForKey:@"color"];   // array of colors.
NSArray *sizes     = [instances valueForKey:@"size"];    // array of sizes.
NSArray *heights   = [instances valueForKey:@"height"];  // array of heights.
NSArray *qualities = [instances valueForKey:@"quality"]; // array of qualities.
```

This will do the trick.

Assuming your items in the `instances` array are numbered from `1..n` a call to `[instances valueForKey:@"number"]` would then return an **NSArray** like `@[@1, @2, @3, @4, ...]`.

Comment: They are already in their own class; see the comments to his question.

Comment: In that case the very last snippet is enough.

Comment: @trojanfoe: See here: [Accessor Search Patterns for Simple Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955). It's some kind of awesomely smart KVC magic method. It basically accomplishes the same (and even more) as your for loop does with a simple method call. With `valueForKeyPath:` one can even provide (period separated) key paths and have it resolve them.

Comment: That's cool; but the OP has objects in an array (not a dictionary) and wants the properties in 5 arrays.  Your code assumes that the values are in a dictionary and you don't show the code to convert **all** the instances into a dictionary.

Comment: No it doesn't. See the guide (which I posted the link to in a previous comment) on how NSArrays respond to `valueForKey:`. In short: they basically forward the message to their content objects and collect their responses into a new array, which then is returned. Read the guide. Worth it. ;) This is how binding to array contents by key path works. Key Value Bindings to "arrangedObjects.foo" on NSArrayController do exactly that (in principle at least), e.g.

Comment: You aren't reading my comments.  Please show the **complete** code snippet that gets the properties from the OP's **array** into 5 arrays.  Not assuming that the properties are in a dictionary, as that isn't where the properties currently are.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Oh, I am reading your comments. But again: Read my code. Then read the programming guide. Then read my code again. And if you run the sample code I just added you'll see that my code does exactly what OP asked for and even works just as expected on NSArrays, NSSets, NSOrderedSets, NSDictionaries, …

Comment: OK I think your code will work and I like the solution, however your answer is still somewhat confusing.  You first talk about using a custom object when the OP is already using a custom object and then you talk about dictionaries but then finally demonstrate that you don't need to use dictionaries at all!

Comment: @trojanfoe: Reworded. Better now?

Comment: Yes much better.  I think this should be accepted as the best solution.

Comment: @Regexident One more question, one of the values in the object is 75.9, but after putting through the array, it turns it to 75.90000000000001. This only happens in one of every ~10 cases, so the other numbers are left untouched. Do you know what causes this problem?

Comment: @mrcharlie: Computers only know binary/octal. Humans (usually) use decimal. Numbers that can be properly (that is without rounding errors) represented in one system need not necessarily be properly representable in another. Software usually counters this by use of some heuristics (basically rounding to the next "round" decimal). The returned numbers should be identical to the ones in your classes though (as `valueForKey:` just returns the collected objects). Compare them with the original number and they should be equal to the last bit, including the error (as it was already there beforehand).

Comment: I realized the error came from somewhere else in the code that I recently changed, heh. Thanks.